# Cmd - find some files and execute a command on that file

Tags: cmd, ffmpeg

In my case, i need to find all .flv files in my drive, transcode them with ffmpeg and then delete them but i don't know how to run the command on each of them

Comment: Hello, what command would you like to run on each file?

Comment: `ffmpeg.exe -i file.flv -vcodec libx265 -bv 800k -acodec mp3 file.mp4`

Comment: This is not a tutorial site, so please take the [tour] and learn [ask]; also take a look at [mcve]! Anyway, check out the [`for` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)...

Comment: In addition to aschipfl's suggestion of `for` loop, the `forfiles` command might be useful. See `forfiles /?` for more information.

Comment: @lit, yes, `forfiles` could be used too, but I recommend not to do that unless you need to filter files by (relative) dates (which `for` is not capable of), because `forfiles` initiates a new `cmd` instance for each loop iteration and is therefore quite slow compared to `for`; also for the sake of code readability, `for` is better as you can easily use a parenthesised code block in the body...

Answer (score -2):

You can list all `.flv` files on your drive like that: `dir /b/s "/**.zip"`. Then you just need to pipe to `ffmpeg`. Then to delete, use `del`.

I'm not sure but it may looks like that:

```
dir /b/s "/**.flv" | ffmpeg
dir /b/s "/**.flv" | del
```

Comment: it doesn't work and i think is because ffmpeg uses a parameter to set the input file

Comment: Well, this is just wrong; haven't you considered testing the code before posting an answer?